# Запись в базу 1 или 0 checkbox

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Есть checkbox. Если его отмечают в поле check таблицы events записывало 1 если снимали отметку, то писало 0. Как это реализовать без отправки формы, а по факту самой отметки данного checkboxa?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: тоесть сейчас отмечают чекбокс а потом нажимают на кнопку отправки формы? А вам нужно по изменению состояния чекбокса?

Comment: Сейчас есть просто чекбокс который находится вне формы. и нужно чтобы он выполнял указанные действия просто по изменению состояния.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type = 'checkbox'  onchange = 'save()' />

function save(){
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: dataType
    }).done(function(answer){

    });
}
```

Если я все правильно понял вот простая реализация. Выполняется скрипт при любом изменении checkbox. Внутри скрипта можно определить состояние чекбокса с  помощью `.prop( "checked" )`. Реализацию на стороне сервера не стал писать. Если надо напишу.

Почитайте про AJAX [тут](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81).

в функции лучше получить значение чекбокса будет выглядеть где-то так:

```
var checkboxState = false;
if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
   checkboxState = true;
}
```

отправить в `data`.

на стороне PHP:

```
$stateCheckbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
$sql = "UPDATE table SET checkbox = $stateCheckbox";
// Выполнение запроса
```

запрос без подготовки просто для "вида". Просто обычный POST никакой магии в конце скрипта php  желательно ответить о удачном завершении, либо ошибке.
можно сделать обычным: `die(json_encode(['code'=>200,'msg'=>'ok']));`

на стороне js в dataType указать json

Comment: Спасибо, как только попробую - отпишусь.

Comment: Если не сложно, на всякий пожарный, можно и серверный вариант, а то я в аяксе полный ноль(

Comment: @DaVinchi Изменил ответ

Comment: Благодарю за ответ и за рекомендации по AJAX. Обязательно воспользуюсь советом)